# Can Composer pick up private github repos via HTTPS?

Tags: php, composer-php

I know that Composer can use registered SSH keys to connect via SSH. I know that it can access public repos via HTTPS. But I saw no example of Composer accessing private repos via HTTPS. How do I set Composer for that?

Comment: If you don't supply an ssh key you will be prompted for your GH username and password with the hips request

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Satis, here is a link to the documentation. https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md